# Pass variables to another pipeline Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, devops

my goal is to get variables from, let's say `pipeA` to `pipeB`.

After pipeA finishes it creates new app version and upload it to AWS S3.

In `pipeB` I want to get all the app versions that was uploaded to S3, so I need to pass appNames to some place.

Then when I build `pipeB` with params I want to get all appNames as params before build, but I can't figure out how.

```
Jenkins ver: 2.141
```

[Example pre build step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qP12F.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Massive edit** workflow is

1. Ask S3 for variables
2. Put this var as choice parameters
3. Select on Jenkins UI some parameter
4. Execute pipeline

In this case `Active Choices Reactive Parameter`, inside use groovy script with return. For example:

```
//S3 file request 
response = ["curl", "-k", 
"-H", "Host: ${bucket}.s3.amazonaws.com", 
"-H", "Date: ${dateValue}", 
"-H", "Authorization: AWS ${s3Key}:${signature}", 
"https://${bucket}.s3.amazonaws.com/${file}"].execute().text 


def choices = []
response.eachLine {
    if (it.contains("Not Found")) {choices.push("There is no file")}
    //here parse your file, in my example is flat custom text
    else {
        if (!it.contains("  ")) {
            param= it.replace(":", "")
            choices.push(param)
        }
    }        
} 
def clean = choices.findAll { item -> !item.isEmpty() } 
return clean.sort()
```

In this way You need insert some param, of course the simplest method is define it in groovy script in plain text:

```
def bucket = '13dfvcqe'
def dateValue = '123'
def s3Key = '1452234F'
def signature = '2133'
def file  = 'vars'
```

This is easy and dangerous :) Better option is fill this confidential value as Jenkins `password parameter` before that param and use `Referenced parameters` option.

Comment: This case is used for one pipeline with job1/job2. I need to execute **pipeline1** with **build job**, then manually start **pipeline2** with parameters that generates **pipeline1**.Flow example:  
(Pipeline1 build start -> build -> generate variable) ->  (Manually start pipeline2 and choose variable from Pipeline1 build results (it could be 10 builds and 10 variables) -> deploy)

Comment: In this case You need use some simple data store like JSON files. So first job must make same add action, and second job need get those variable. Read this http://groovy-lang.org/json.html, and https://gist.github.com/atomsfat/6273637 for working with JSON, and S3.

Comment: Okay I see, but how I can execute request to my s3 then get **variables** and add it as choice parameter to select **var** before build?  Flow example: Ask S3 for **variables** -> put this **var** as choice parameters -> select on Jenkins UI some parameter -> execute pipeline.

Comment: Nice, thank you. Is there is a way to debug script in "choose source" field? Because I am trying to execute this command and I get nothing:  
`def res = sh(script: "aws elasticbeanstalk describe-application-versions --application-name MyApp", returnStdout: true)`
I think I need to wait some time to shell command resolve?

Comment: It can take a few moments, but it's time very similar to normal shell execute. For debug create new Job and past this code as `pipeline` code with Scripted Pipeline syntax(it's easier and faster to write). Instead `return` at the end use `println`